# How to hide menu product page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, development, customize

I need help to know How to edit, delete or hide menu (More Information and Reviews) on product page magento 2.

http://prntscr.com/v91f8b

Comment: Please add more information.

Comment: Try this.
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true"></referenceBlock>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go To this file and paste below two lines if not file available in your theme then you create it

> app/design/frontend//Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this via Layout XML

like

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
```

or remove tab with reviews

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
```

Comment: please check update me.

Comment: Hello can you give me path to edit line?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove product tabs by removing it in catalog_product_view.xml file.

`<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true"/>`

`<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"/>`

Comment: Hello can you show me path to edited

Comment: You can go to you theme folder app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xm